# SQL query: finding an average

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in sql and I came across a problem:
Let's say I have the following tables:

- SIGNALS - sent from chips on a regular basis (KEY: (chip_id  REF chips, signal_number))
- RECEIVERS - signal receivers, stations which can receive a signal when its in its range        (KEY: receiver_id)
- RECEIVINGS - facts of receiving of a signal (KEY: Chip_id, signal_number, receiver_id)

I was wondering if there is any way without using php to make a query that shows the percentage of signals that have been received.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: How do you define the average in this context? And specifically, what is the total count to get the percentage?

Comment: SELECT(SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM RECEIVINGS)/(SELECT COUNT(\*) FROM SIGNALS)

Comment: It would probably help if we had full schemas of the tables and some sample data and expected results. It should be a fairly simple bit of code to get what you want though.

Comment: @Simon How do you calculate percentage of signal received ?I mean provide a sample data for `signals` and `receivings` .

Comment: @PatrickStephansen Yes that's it, just one more thing remaining: I think the values this is counting are integers, how can I make it to float data so it shows a proper percentage?

Comment: @Simon : Are you interested in average signals received per receiver? Or an overall average of signals sent vs received? Let's say one chip, CHIP_1 transmits a signal and there are 10 receivers but only 2 received it and the other 8 (being out of range) didn't receive it then are you still interested in overall average or you are looking for an average number of signals actually received by each receiver?

Comment: @MAnthony well, I assume a signal, when sent, can be received by just one receiver, so what i'd like to find is a sum of all signals sent, divided by the sum of all receivings - Patrick has done it in the comment above, but now what Im struggling with is casting those messages to float

Comment: OK got it now, thanks to all :) `SELECT CAST((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM RECEIVINGS)AS FLOAT)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIGNALS), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RECEIVINGS), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIGNALS)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 CAST((SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM RECEIVINGS)AS FLOAT)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIGNALS),
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RECEIVINGS), 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SIGNALS)
```